# Existence of isolated point.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, baire-category

Suppose: A is a countable closed subset of a complete metric space.

Prove: A contains at least one isolated point.

(the Baire category theorem brings me no further than Int(A) (the interior of A) is empty)

Answer (score 2):

Consider $A$ as its own metric space now with the subspace topology. Notice that $A$ is complete so the Baire Category theorem applies. Now suppose that for every $x \in A$, $\{x\}$ is *not* open. In particular this means that $\{x\}$ is nowhere dense. But then since $A$ is countable, $A$ is a countable union of nowhere dense singletons, so $A$ is meager. But the Baire Category theorem applies on $A$, and by the Baire Category theorem, a complete metric space is not meager. So we have a contradiction.